# Pushing data from an API to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xmlhttprequest

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass along data from an API to an array. What I'm trying to do is to fetch the current population of a country and then put it in the array. Which country depends on the input.

Am I on the right track? How can I do this? I've tried so much different, and this code is the latest I've gotten.

```
document
  .querySelector("#newListElement")
  .addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    getCountry(country).then(function() {
      list.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        text: e.target.elements.text.value
        /* How do I send along Country Population Today with this object?*/
      });

      saveListElements(list);
      renderList(list);
      e.target.elements.text.value = "";
    });
  });

function getCountry(country) {
  var url = `http://api.population.io/1.0/population/${country}/today-and-tomorrow`;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "json";

    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status === 200) {
        resolve(request.response);
      } else {
        reject(Error(request.statusText));
      }

      request.onerror = function() {
        reject(Error("Network Error"));
      };

      request.send();
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Place print statements inside your resolver and see what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read that page before going further

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

```
//the promise's result is the first argument of the resolve handler.
getCountry(country).then(function(myResult) { 
      list.push({
        id: uuidv4(),
        text: e.target.elements.text.value,
        result:myResult
      });

      saveListElements(list);
      renderList(list);
      e.target.elements.text.value = "";
    });
```